# How to add additional source files in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have a Makefile that I use to build executable on mac os x, using mpicc compiler, linking mkl_lapack.h library.
Now this Makefile is perfectly working, the only problem is that I don't know what to add if I want to compile Eigenvalues.c linking other .c files, if I want to link myfile.c where do I have to write it in Makefile?

```
MKL_INCLUDE=/opt/intel/mkl/include
MKLROOT=/opt/intel/mkl/lib

CC = mpicc
LD = mpicc
IFLAGS = -I$(MKL_INCLUDE)
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 $(IFLAGS) -std=c99

LFLAGS =  $(MKLROOT)/libmkl_intel_lp64.a $(MKLROOT)/libmkl_sequential.a    $(MKLROOT)/libmkl_core.a  -lpthread -lm 

PROGRAMS = Eigenvalues

all: $(PROGRAMS)

Eigenvalues: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS) 

%.o: %.c
    @echo C compiling $@
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(PROGRAMS)

Eigenvalues: Eigenvalues.c
```

Comment: LFLAGS is traditionally the name of flags passed to lex, while LDFLAGS is the name used for flags passed to the linker.  See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply have the `Eigenvalues` target depend on all the `.o` files (*not* the `.c` files, as you have!) that make up the application.  Conventionally, the list of these objects is put in a variable:

```
PROGRAMS = Eigenvalues
Eigenvalues_OBJS = Eigenvalues.o foo.o bar.o #etc

all: $(PROGRAMS)

Eigenvalues: $(Eigenvalues_OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS) 

# delete the "Eigenvalues: Eigenvalues.c" line,
# leave everything else as you have it
```

By the way, since you are using the standard variable names `$(CC)` and `$(CFLAGS)`, you can leave out the `%.o: %.c` rule entirely; Make has a built-in rule that does the same thing.

Comment: Almost standard names: -I(eye) should go in CPPFLAGS, and -l(ell) belong in LDFLAGS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this mate!

```
PROGRAMS = Eigenvalues

MKL_INCLUDE=/opt/intel/mkl/include 
MKLROOT=/opt/intel/mkl/lib 

IFLAGS = -I$(MKL_INCLUDE) 
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 $(IFLAGS) -std=c99 

LFLAGS =  $(MKLROOT)/libmkl_intel_lp64.a $(MKLROOT)/libmkl_sequential.a
$(MKLROOT)/libmkl_core.a  -lpthread -lm  


all: $(PROGRAMS).c

OBJS = \
Eigenvalues.o \
myfile.o\

##############################################################################
.SUFFIXES : .c .o

CC = mpicc 
LD = mpicc 
RM = rm -rf

$(PROGRAMS).c : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)  

clean: 
    $(RM) *.o $(OBJS) $(PROGRAMS) 

.c.o :
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```